# Trying to change fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

so far that's my code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sc \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rm \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```

What it produces is the page number in the left hand top corner and the chaptername in the top right hand corner including a ruler on every second page.

How can I change this that it also displays a "Chapter 1. Text" where chapter is italic and text is roman?

Tried some stuff but it never changed how I wanted it to be.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I tried to use
  `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
    \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}`
as given in the fancyhdr documentation but it does not change at all. Could it be a problem that I use my own .cls file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alter the commands in `\chaptermark`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textit{\chaptername\ 
\thechapter.} #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sc \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rm \nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

If you use the `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` structuring commands then you may wish to use the following definition instead:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\if@mainmatter\textit{\chaptername\ \thechapter. }\fi #1}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Additionally at any `\chapter*` command you will want to issue an appropriate `\markboth`.

Comment: This has undesired effects if `\chapter` (not `\chapter*`) is used in the `\frontmatter` or in the `\backmatter`

Comment: Sorry it does not work. Is it a problem that I don't use book.cls?

Comment: @egreg Can you ellaborate?

Comment: Which class are you using?

Comment: If you say `\chapter{Preface}` after `\frontmatter` and before `\mainmatter`, the header will be "Chapter 0. Preface".

Comment: @egreg I see what you mean.  `\chapter*` is also problematic, as usual.

Comment: I use a self made .cls but in that I load this:
`\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`
and of course
`\Requirepackage{fancyhdr}`

Comment: I think it is as you said a problem with those \chapter and  \chpater* commands. It just works in the frontmatter and then there is the problem with Chapter 0. But it does not work properly in the mainmatter. :/

Comment: @Kenjiiii Can you add more detailed code to your question?  You could try moving the definitions to immediately after `\mainmatter`.

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks

Just add "Chapter" to `\markboth` and make sure your document uses the option `twoside` to distinguish between even and odd pages.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=10cm,top=2cm]{geometry}% ridiculous page size
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textit{Chapter \thechapter}\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{Section \thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\scshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Text}
\section{Next text}
\lipsum[1-2]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image] [image]